# Eclipse and EGit: Can't export SSH

Tags: eclipse, git, ssh, egit

I tried to set up a ssh connection in order to be able to **pull git repositories with EGit in Eclipse via ssh**. (I'm using Eclipse Luna).
For this I used instructions given on the Eclipse Wiki.

I went to **Eclipse --> Windows --> Preferences --> General --> Network Connection --> SSH2 --> Key Management --> Generate RSA Key**
 and tried to export the key via the "**Export via SFTP**" Button. I entered 
**githubID@git.eclipse.org** but instead of exporting my key, an error appeared on top of the window (**"failed to export ssh key to remote server"**)

I did the whole process a few month ago (that worked) and only wanted to redo this, because pulling my repository caused an error.
Old pull Error:
**ssh://githubID@git.eclipse.org/gitroot/myproject.git: Session.connect: java.io.IOException: End of IO Stream Read**

I have read about an update of EGit and updated it as well as trying the whole process on a new laptop, but the error also occurs in the new laptop with a new Eclipse.

Does anybody knows a solution for my problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you use a 'githubID' at eclipse.org or did you mean the Eclipse committer account name?

Comment: I mean the Eclipse committer account name I think. In my Eclipse account this is called "GithubID" (It's the displayed name on my commits in the repos etc.)

Comment: If you are accessing a git repository hosted on eclipse.org you will need to pass your Eclipse committer account name which may be different from your GitHub user id. The Eclipse committer account name is usually the first letter of your first name plus your last name.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My committer account name seems to be my githubID as that is the first letter of my first name + my last name. The strange thing is, that a few month ago everything worked fine...

Comment: Did you eclipse.org password expire?

Comment: Indeed, my eclipse.org password expired when I was on holiday a few weeks ago. But I could reset it and I'm able to login on the Eclipse website without any problems. Do I have to change my password on another platform?

Comment: No, not that I am aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I ended up asking the Eclipse Webmaster for help.
As my IP address hasn't been blocked (This might have been a solution!) I tried to use the Git Bash instead of EGit and that's worked! So it wasn't a problem with my ssh key, but with the Client, which seems to be broken.

It's more work to do all git commands manually, but finally it works.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug in older versions of eGit.

Related: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1096174/

However, the most recent versions of eGit are not compatible with Eclipse Luna any more.
For me, upgrading eGit to version 5.0.3, the last version compatible with Eclipse Luna by manually downloading eGit from here http://archive.eclipse.org/egit/updates-5.0.3/ and installing it from local solved the problem.